# How to use a wildcard expression within system()

Tags: c++, linux, shell, system, wildcard

The following command runs fine on my embedded Linux (Beaglebone Black):

```
echo bone_pwm_P9_21 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.?/slots
```

But not when using this small C++ program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

int main {
    system(std::string("echo bone_pwm_P9_21 > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.?/slots").c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

The problem involves the `'?'` question mark, that is used as a wildcard.
When the question mark, in the `std::string` that is passed to `system()`, is replaced with a normal character, the `system()` function evaluates the command perfect.

Solutions I've tried without success:

- replace `?` with `\?`
- replace `?` with `*`

Comment: I think that regex is a feature of the shell you're using, not working for system calls.

Comment: As a side note, the conversion you are making from C-style string to std::string and back seems pointless.

Comment: _"Solutions I've tried without success:"_ Can you elaborate about what exactly failed? `\?` escaping with backslash should do the trick.

Comment: @Heron That _regex_ is called _wildcard_ and is a shell feature, yes.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What happens?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, if "the trick" was to unambiguously _prevent_ expansion, yes, it would... but the goal here is to _force_ expansion in a context where pure POSIX doesn't require shells to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** As πάντα ῥεῖ pointed out the `system()` command calls the shell which will usually do the expansion when presented with the correct wildcard: `*`. This answer is thereful more appropriate if you want the control to make each `system()` call separately or if the underlying shell is limited.

**Original answer:**

Perhaps you could use **[wordexp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wordexp)**  for this to construct your strings before you make the `system()` call:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <wordexp.h>

std::vector<std::string> expand_env(const std::string& var, int flags = 0)
{
    std::vector<std::string> vars;

    wordexp_t p;
    if(!wordexp(var.c_str(), &p, flags))
    {
        if(p.we_wordc)
            for(char** exp = p.we_wordv; *exp; ++exp)
                vars.push_back(exp[0]);
        wordfree(&p);
    }
    return vars;
}

int main()
{
    for(auto&& s: expand_env("$HOME/*")) // <= Note the wildcard '*'
        std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

In your specific case you could perhaps use something like this:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> devices = expand_env("/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.*/slots");

    for(std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0; i < devices.size(); ++i)
        system(("echo bone_pwm_P9_21 > " + devices[i]).c_str());
}
```

Comment: `system()` already calls a shell, and wildcard expansion should be done properly by it, as long the characters are passed correctly. `?` is a special character in c++ string literals. I don't see a point to use `wordexp()` here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are right. I will modify the answer to explain when this method is useful.

Comment: `?` is not a special character in C/C++ literals. It is used in the so-called trigraphs, but here it is not the case. All trigraphs start with two question marks.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from your code not being compilable, this fails because `system(3)` runs `sh`, often a minimal shell provided by `dash` or `busybox`.

Meanwhile, your interactive login uses `bash`, `ksh` or some other more comfy shell.

`dash` and `busybox sh` do not do glob expansion on redirections, while `bash` and `ksh` do. Here's a demonstration of the behavior you want courtesy of `bash`:

```
$ touch file.txt

$ bash -c 'echo "bash contents" > *.txt'

$ cat file.txt
bash contents
```

Meanwhile, the problem you're having with e.g. `dash`:

```
$ dash -c 'echo "and now dash" > *.txt'

$ ls
*.txt  file.txt

$ cat '*.txt'      # Instead of expanding, the path was taken literally
and now dash

$ cat file.txt
bash contents
```

To fix this, you can (in order of preference)

1. Write your C program in C code instead of shell script
2. Call a better shell with `execve`.
3. Rewrite to not write to a glob, e.g. `echo "stuff" | tee *.txt > /dev/null`
4. Call a better shell with `system`, e.g. `bash -c "echo stuff > *.txt"`